# Posting Json data with Guzzle Client in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, httprequest, guzzle

I am trying to post some data using a Guzzle Client Http request in Laravel. But for some reason the server respons with the message that it can't find the property `Id` in the JSON object, while the property `Id` is clearly in the request. The [Guzzle documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json) says that assigning the array to a `json` property in the request will result in a Json object being sent.

```
$url = "https://blablabla.com/api";
$key = "1234";
$data = [
    'Id' => "4"
    ];
$response = Http::withHeaders([
    "Authorization" =>  $key
])->post($url, [
    'json' => $data
]);
```

Now I have tested the api in Postman and don't experience any problems. I even use the same api in a different php application using curl and it works perfect. So obviously there is something wrong with lines of code above and not with the api. I have tried different things but nothing works.. I have a feeling that the solution is so simple.. but for the last 6 hours I couldn't figure it out.. So please help before I go crazy :)

Comment: Try ``id`` instead of ``Id``.

Comment: Is the target expecting the data inside the `json` key? I'm assuming you probably just want `$response = Http::withHeaders(["Authorization" =>  $key])->post($url, $data);`, but we have no idea the format your endpoint is expecting. What did your successful postman request look like?

Comment: @Dula Nope. Server expects `Id` not `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests) on page HTTP Client says: "By default, data will be sent using the application/json content type". So you don't need to use 'json' property in post data. Just sent it directly: `->post($url, $data)`.

Comment: When I don't use the json propert I get  an error saying that the deserialize the json object.

Comment: Can you give me full error